# Do lights and music enhance a cocktail?

Tags: taste, cocktails

OK, so here I sit, in a fantastic marina (yes I live on a boat), but every Saturday and Sunday night the local cocktail bar has a rather serious disco, or should I say Saturday morning/Sunday morning (as they finish at 6am!).  I have friends who state that the cocktails they drink in the bar taste better when they are there during disco night than when they are there on a normal night - how does this happen?

Comment: Yes, the doooog is back!

Comment: Where are you now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's been proven scientifically!

Here is an [article](https://www.sciencefriday.com/articles/does-sound-affect-the-way-we-taste/) that breaks it down

> On the other hand, some research suggests that, under the right conditions, loud noise might actually enhance certain flavors

Are these people on vacation? It's a well known fact that things taste better on vacation. [Why wine tastes better on vacation](https://www.travelbelles.com/2012/11/wine-doesnt-taste-same-at-home/)

> Reason 1: The answer you’ve probably heard or read before: you’re in Europe! You’re relaxed. Everything is going to taste better.

Actually you could scratch "Europe" and put anywhere you are on vacation.

Comment: Cool!  Not a vacation a lifestyle.  Do you have any idea of how to stop them from blasting bang bang music into my ear at 5 in the morning?